# Can't find replicaset kube state metrics in Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kube-state-metrics

I'm trying to set some alarms based on replica set metrics but Prometheus cannot find [replicaset kube state metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/replicaset-metrics.md) while browsing expressions. What would be the problem with that? On Prometheus dashboard, I can see lots of metrics, which is in kube state metrics repo, but replica sets. Any ideas?

Kube state metrics  version: v1.9.7

Update:

For example, I can see most of [deployment metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/deployment-metrics.md) on the dashboard, but no metrics for replica sets.

[image]

Comment: Hi, @cosmos-1905-14 Which version of Kubernetes are you using?

Comment: Hi @AndrewSkorkin I'm using `1.18`

Comment: I've tried to reproduce this issue on Kubernetes 1.18 with different versions of kube-state-metrics: 1.8, 1.9.7. `kube_replicaset_...` metrics available for me. So, kube-state-metrics support them for such version. Do you have ReplicaSets deployed right now?

Comment: the issue is resolved upon checking `kube-state-metric` logs. SA hasn't enough privileges to access replicasets.

Comment: Fine! Since the issue resolved, could you please provide your resolution as an answer not a comment? It will be useful for other people to see founded solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, `replicasets` in the ClusterRole was missing. After adding [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/examples/standard/cluster-role.yaml#L34) line, the problem resolved. Thanks @Andrew Skorkin to remind me of checking logs.

Answer (score 1):

This is a community wiki answer posted for better clarity. Feel free to expand it.

As @ cosmos-1905-14 described, he checked the kube-state-metric logs and found that the ServiceAccount did not have sufficient rights to access the ReplicaSets. After he added the necessary rights, the issue was resolved.